# New Object with 1:n Properties

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

Is it possible to create a new Object in Extbase 7.6 with 1:n Properties? Out of the box?

Something like this:

```
<f:form.textfield property="openinghours.NEW1.start" />
<f:form.textfield property="openinghours.NEW1.end" />
<f:form.textfield property="openinghours.NEW2.start" />
<f:form.textfield property="openinghours.NEW2.end" />
<f:form.textfield property="openinghours.NEW3.start" />
<f:form.textfield property="openinghours.NEW3.end" />
```

etc. pp

As you can see I want to add 1:n opening hours to a new object. My example isn't working, obviously otherwise i wouldn't ask. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. It is important that the Subobject is declared as ObjectStorage and you have to allow the rendering of subobjects inside the initializeXY-Actions in the controller.
Heres a helpful - german - article about this: http://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/core/systemextensions/extbase/property-mapper.html

Comment: Thank's mate, awsome! :)